# Loging into file error while windows service is running

Tags: c#, logging, windows-services

i have windows service which i installed using `installutill` command and it is running successfully.

1-i map the config as log in to `file`.

2-it is not creating a log file while the service is running.when i double click on .exe file.

3-it shows an error that " installation must be completed using util command " and suddenly after that it creates a log file in my desired location.it shows message as

```
  "my-service going to be started"
```

4-i want to do that when i starts service then log file must be present in my desired location.

any idea where i am getting error?

Comment: what is the exact error you are getting? Can you make your question clearer?

Comment: it is not making a log on stop . on pause etc etc

Comment: even when i started service through windows service explorer it never makes a log in my location...........it is not loging !